# C++: Using function overloading with implicit conversion between char to int or vice versa

Tags: c++, char, int, implicit-conversion, overloading

In C++, if `char` to `int` is implicit conversion and `int` to `char` is also implicit conversion. Normally, a `char` is single or double byte. On 32-bit machine an `int` is usually 4-byte. Thus, `int to char` conversion has the possibility of data loss (as moving from bigger area to smaller storage area), where as `char to int` is more logical candidate for implicit conversion.
Now, what about this?
Say, we attempt to overload functions with arguments as `(int, char)` and another as `(char, int)`, if I call the function with `(char, char)`, would this be ambiguous or call to `(char, int)` is more logical? 
For example,

```
void f(char a, int b)
{
    cout << "f(char, int) called" << endl;
}

void f(int a, char b)
{
    cout << "f(int, char) called " << endl;
}

int main()
{
    char a = 'a', b = 'b';
    f(a, b); // which overloaded function should be called?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] to illustrate your question; you might also find this will answer your question.

Comment: *"Normally, a char is single or double byte"*. No. `char` is never two bytes. It is always exactly one byte.

Comment: @user2079303 a char is 1 char - a byte is something else.

Comment: Neither: `error: call of overloaded 'f(char&, char&)' is ambiguous`

Comment: @RichardCritten whether they are same or something else does not affect my statement. Size of `char` is 1 byte according to the C++ standard.

Comment: @Richard - Unfortunately the C++ standard has its own definition of the term byte, making it the same size as a `char` - *at least* 8 bits, instead of the more common *exactly* 8 bits. And `sizeof(char) == 1` by that definition.

Comment: @user2079303 You are (both) right and I was confused.  Was miss-remembering that a Byte need not be 8 bits.

Comment: Why do you think call to `(char, int)` is more logical? there is no `int` to `char` conversion in your example. Do you mean overloading `(char, char)` and `(int, int)` then calling `(char, int)`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have two overloads like:

```
auto foo(int, char) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

auto foo(char, int) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
```

And then try to call:

```
foo('a', 'a');
```

then the call is *ambiguous*.

For instance, *gcc* [reports](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VqVOmUa74kI8XbL5) that:

```
error: call of overloaded 'foo(char, char)' is ambiguous
     foo('a', 'a');
                 ^
note: candidate: 'auto foo(int, char)'
 auto foo(int, char) {
      ^~~
note: candidate: 'auto foo(char, int)'
 auto foo(char, int) {
      ^~~
```

And it makes a perfect sense: the compiler might either promote first `char` argument to `int` and call the first overload. Or it might do the same for the second argument. Both ways are equally valid. So the compiler complains.

If you want to call a concrete version, you might use `static_cast`:

```
static_cast<void(*)(int, char)>(foo)('a', 'a');
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now, what about this? Say, we attempt to overload functions with arguments as (int, char) and another as (char, int), if I call the function with (char, char), would this be ambiguous

Yes, it would be ambiguous. Both candidate conversion sequences consist of same number of equally preferred conversion steps.